# I wrote a verilog code but got errors like not a constant or unknown type

Tags: error-handling, verilog, fpga, system-verilog

How can I remove the errors mentioned in the title?

```
  reg [3:0]count;
  reg [6:0]seg;

  always @ (posedge clock) begin
    if (reset)
      count = 0;
    else
      count = count+1'b0;   //starting A counter
  end

  begin // this seems to need an "always @*" just before "begin"
    case(count)
      4'b0000: seg = 7'b0000001;
    endcase
  end

  assign {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} = seg;

endmodule  // where is "module"?
```

It shows error 44 i.e. count is not a constant
 Error 1059 i.e. seg is of unknown type. Please help. 
can't figure out what to do next

Comment: this site is for asking specific questions from which others might profit too, not to do your work for you. it looks a bit like you should first learn how to use verilog in general; maybe follow a few tutorials.

Comment: in the example `clock`, `reset` and `a,b,c,d,e,f,g` are not defined.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a 7-segment counter that displays an hexadecimal value based on the value of a running 4-bit counter.

First, you need to declare inputs and outputs of your module, which can be done (in Verilog 2001) as this:

```
module counter7seg (
  input wire clock,
  input wire reset,
  output wire a,
  output wire b,
  output wire c,
  output wire d,
  output wire e,
  output wire f,
  output wire g
  );
```

This part of your description looks almost fine: a 4 bit counter. But you need (as Morgan pointed) to fix two things: assignments within a clocked `always` must be nonblocking ( `<=` instead of `=` ), and your counter, to be able to count, must add `1`, not `0`:

```
  always @ (posedge clock) begin
    if (reset)
      count <= 0;
    else
      count <= count+1'b1;   //starting A counter
  end
```

The following part, when you take the value of `count` and derive values for the segments, is incomplete: you need 16 cases here.

I can see that you use negative logic to switch on segments, so effectively, `0000` becomes `0000001`, `0001` becomes (just guessing by the contents of picture below) `1001111`,.... `1000` becomes `0000000`, and so on.

[image: 7 segment display]

```
  always @* begin
    case(count)  // 16 cases here + default
      4'b0000: seg = 7'b0000001; // 0
      4'b0001: seg = 7'b1001111; // 1
      4'b0010: seg = 7'b0110110; // 2
      //......
      //......
      4'b1000: seg = 7'b0000000; // 8
      //......
      //......
      4'b1111: seg = 7'b0110000; // a nice capital F
      default: seg = 7'b1111111; // a default case with all segments off
    endcase
  end
```

Comment: Ups, yes! Ill fix that

Comment: Thank you for your response . I did make the corrections you suggested . But still it shows the two errors I mentioned earlier .

Comment: Can you post the complete module?